# Get the results from a mysql_query insert

Tags: php, mysql

After I insert values into a new row, I need the results from that query.
`mysql_query()` only returns true or false when doing a INSERT command.
The only solution I can think of for something like this is by creating a temporary number/id in PHP and inserting it into its own column. Then fetching that row it with a second command.
However it may be possible that my random id is not random enough to accidentally select the wrong row when the script is executed multiple times.

Is there a way to execute the INSERT command on a `mysql_query()` call so that it returns the rows created?

Comment: What kind of data, that you are inserting, you don't know so you have to retrieve it? Apart from the id, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and [`mysql_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). `AUTO_INCREMENT` will create a unique ID for each row automatically which you can retrieve using `mysql_insert_id()`;